# How to test graph by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, graph, junit, mouse

I am trying to test the INTERACTIVE GRAPH on this website by using JUnit and Selenium: https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/

I want to move the mouse on the curve for each day point, and get the date and amount value.

1. I do not know what is the input for moving the mouse on the curve?
2. I do not know which Selenium function I use to move?
3. how to get the data and amount value for each move?

Could some expert help me on this? I am a freshman to use Selenium.

Thanks so much.

[image]
[image]

Comment: some of the tips, you can try :
1. Maximize the browser window
2.check for whether you are trying to figure 30 days, 60 days or 90 days.
3.check the current date and that will be the day on the last part, you can check the first one by subtracting your days accordingly.
4. Now just use mouseOver with the width and height and observe the readings...

Hope it will somewhat help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Given a selected day, how could I move the mouse to that day with width and height?